# What is a persistent variable?

Tags: regression

What is a persistent variable in the context of regression analysis? For example, dividend to price ratio (D/P) is considered to be persistent variable when used to model future returns (Stambaugh Bias literature).

Comment: I think this question is more suitable in http://stats.stackexchange.com/ In short, persistence is related to the long-term influence of a shock, e. g. that a one-off shock on the d/p would have an "everlasting" influence on the average return level.

Comment: Sounds about right. If you submit this as an answer... I'll tick it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, persistence is related to the long-term influence of a shock, e. g. that a one-off shock on the d/p would have an "everlasting" influence on the average return level.

Comment: Whoever downgraded, would you mind answering as well?